# What does SSL certificate problem means in vsCode or Git Bash?

Tags: git, ssl

I'm trying to add my vsCode Python project to my GitHub account but I get that : "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"
What should I do?
I could also do these with git commands. But I get the same problem here.

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Check in command line the output of `git config -l --show-origin --show-scope | grep -i ssl`

If you see anything related to sslCA, remove that setting. The default certificates which come with Git for Windows should be adequat to access `https://github.com`.